# Adding additional text in a legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am learning Tikz/Pgfplots and I am trying to recreate the following graph

[image: first graph]

So far I have been able to come up with the following:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[axis lines = center, axis equal image,
          domain = -2.5:2.5,
          ymax=4.5,
          tick label style = {font=\scriptsize},
          xtick = {0, 1},
          xticklabels = {0, 1},
          legend entries = {$a^x$, $b^x$},
          ytick = {0.5, 1, 2},
          yticklabels = {b, 1, a},
          xlabel= \(x\),
          ylabel= \(y\),
          legend style={at={(0.03,0.3)},anchor=west},
          font=\scriptsize]
        \addplot[red, name path=expg1] {2^x};
        \addplot[blue, name path=expl1] {0.5^x};
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:$(1,a)$}] at
    (1,2){};
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:$(1,b)$}] at
    (1,0.5){};
        \draw[dashed,help lines] (1,0) -- (1,2);
        \draw[dashed,help lines] (1,2) -- (0,2);
        \draw[dashed,help lines] (1,0.5) -- (0,0.5);
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and the result is:

[image: second graph]

which is fine, but I haven't been able to add the informations "a>1" and "0<b<1" in the legend: when I try to modify

```
    legend entries = {$a^x$, $b^x$}
```

to
legend entries = {$a^x, a>1$, $b^x, 0<b<1$}

the file does not compile (I am using Overleaf) and I haven't been able to figure out another way to add this information.
So, I would be grateful if someone could explain me how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "protect" the internal commas `,` from the option parser --- just surround every entry between additional braces.

I also added a bit of code to change the line-up of the labels in the box (the part `nodes={...}` in the legend style) and an explicit space `\;` after the comma in math mode.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[axis lines = center, axis equal image,
          domain = -2.5:2.5,
          ymax=4.5,
          tick label style = {font=\scriptsize},
          xtick = {0, 1},
          xticklabels = {0, 1},
          legend entries = {{$a^x,\;a>0$}, {$b^x,\; 0<b<1$}},
          ytick = {0.5, 1, 2},
          yticklabels = {b, 1, a},
          xlabel= \(x\),
          ylabel= \(y\),
          legend style={at={(0.03,0.3)},anchor=west,nodes={right, font=\scriptsize}},
          font=\scriptsize]
        \addplot[red, name path=expg1] {2^x};
        \addplot[blue, name path=expl1] {0.5^x};
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:$(1,a)$}] at (1,2){};
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:$(1,b)$}] at (1,0.5){};
        \draw[dashed,help lines] (1,0) -- (1,2);
        \draw[dashed,help lines] (1,2) -- (0,2);
        \draw[dashed,help lines] (1,0.5) -- (0,0.5);
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS next time, please avoid posting snippets of code that are not self-contained: add the boilerplate around it so that people can just copy and paste it, and compile it.